Why is it whenever I create a sub class I am unable to access particular functions in Pycharm?
Here I have created a Car Class. I have also created another class called Battery and then a sub class ElectricCar that takes from the Car class. I then begin to create an Instance Tesla then I connect it to the Car class, at this point everything is fine. However when I write Tesla.upgrade() for some reason Pycharm/Python does not recognise the function, does anyone know why this is I dont want to remove the  subclasses.
class Car:
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes to describe a car."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
        print(f"This car has {self.odometer_reading} miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """Set the odometer reading to the given value."""
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        """Add the given amount to the odometer reading."""
        self.odometer_reading += miles


class Battery:
    def __init__(self, battery_size=40):
        """Initialize the battery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
        print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        """Print a statement about the range this battery provides."""
        if self.battery_size == 40:
            range = 150
        elif self.battery_size == 65:
            range = 225

        print(f"This car can go about {range} miles on a full charge.")

    def upgrade_battery(self):
        """Upgrade the battery if possible."""
        if self.battery_size == 40:
            self.battery_size = 65
            print("Upgraded the battery to 65 kWh.")
        else:
            print("The battery is already upgraded.")


class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """
        Initialize attributes of the parent class.
        Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()


Tesla = Car("Telsa", "Cybertruck", "2024")
Tesla.upgrade_battery()


You haven't created an instance of the subclass.

Is this just a problem with a PyCharm warning, or do you get an error when running the script?

@Barmar it tells me 'Car' object has no attribute "upgrade_battery"

An electric car has a battery; it is not a kind of battery itself.

upgrade_battery() is a method of the Battery class, not Car.

If you are trying to accurately model a car, you probably can't just change the size of an existing battery; you need to replace battery of one size with an entirely new batter with a bigger size. In that case, upgrade_battery should be an ElectricCar method that changes the value of the battery attribute, rather than a Battery method that changes the size of an existing battery.

upgrade_battery() is a method of Battery, not Car.
The Car class doesn't have a battery, only ElectricCar does. So you need to make an instance of ElectricCar, then call the method on its battery attribute.
tesla = ElectricCar("Telsa", "Cybertruck", "2024")
tesla.battery.upgrade_battery()

